# Font-size gets overwritten even with !important

Tags: html, css

I'm using the follow PHP to output some tags on my blog:

```
foreach ($tagvalues as $tag => $count) {
    $size = 12 + $count * 2;
    echo '<div class="tag" style=" font-size:' . $size . ' !important; "> ' . $tag . ' </div>';
}
```

Which results in this HTML on my blog:

```
...
<div class="tag" style=" font-size:14 !important; "> career </div>
<div class="tag" style=" font-size:16 !important; "> parenting </div>
...
```

As you can see I'm trying to set each tag's size according to the number of instances. The code output fines but all the tags appear the same size. When I look at it with developer tools in Chrome I see that the font-size attribute is overwritten by nothing! The font-size for these tags is not set anywhere else and I'm really puzzled as to why it's ignored/overwritten.

[You can see my site here (need to click on **My Blog** to load tags)](http://rlcoaching.com/)

Comment: try this `font-size:' . $size . 'px !important;`

Comment: An observation... do you really want to use pixel size directly derived from some count value? I'd figure out an er, more robust solution. The answer below solves your problem though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need the `!important` because of the CSS order precedence (you're applying inline styles). The problem is you're missing the `px`,

Eg.

```
<div class="tag" style=" font-size:16px"> parenting </div>
```